# how to add a field in my table that is auto_incremented from 001 to 999 besides its original ID

Tags: mysql, sql, datatable, auto-increment, digits

```
CREATE TABLE `opportunity` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `account_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Comment: why do you need 001 to 999?

Comment: *from 001 to 999* But somewhen the rows amount will reach 1000...

Comment: yeah i need it when it hits 1000 row to reset to 000

Comment: Ann other solution is to use the right 3 digits of the column 'id', they start from 0 and stop at 999. You could use a calculate column for so you can use it in query's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have only one autoincrement column on a table, and in any case, if I'm not mistaken, MySQL doesn't have the ability to "cycle" the increment. To achieve what you're asking for, I think you'd need to create and attach a BEFORE INSERT trigger routine.

Comment: yes i will implement the logic in the code before inserting thx